# How to save the generated picture instead of the form of a web page in R?

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
provname=c("CN-11","CN-12","CN-13","CN-14","CN-15",
    "CN-21","CN-22","CN-23","CN-31","CN-32",
    "CN-33","CN-34","CN-35","CN-36","CN-37",
    "CN-41","CN-42","CN-43","CN-44","CN-45",
    "CN-46","CN-50","CN-51","CN-52","CN-53",
    "CN-54","CN-61","CN-62","CN-63","CN-64","CN-65");
    pop=c(110.56,112.51,113.43,112.52,108.45,112.83,111.23,109.71,110.64,116.51,
      113.86,127.85,117.93,114.74,112.17,118.46,128.18,126.16,130.30,
      125.55,135.64,115.13,116.01,107.03,108.71,102.73,122.10,114.82,
      110.35,108.79,106.12)
    ## 
    library(googleVis)
    a<-data.frame(provname,pop)
    G1 <- gvisGeoMap(a, locationvar='provname', numvar='pop',options=list(region='CN'))
    plot(G1) 
    ##
    G2 <- gvisGeoChart(a, locationvar='provname', colorvar='pop',options=list(region='CN',displayMode="regions",resolution="provinces",colorAxis="{colors: ['yellow','red']}" ))
    plot(G2)
```

Comment: You can't. Just take a screenshot.

Comment: Methinks folks are a bit quick on the draw with the "cannot be done".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `webshot` package. The `plot` method for `googleVis` objects returns the path to the HTML file. Save that into a variable and you can do:

```
library(webshot)

out <- plot(G2)
webshot(out, delay=2)
```

[image]

You can customize the height, width, clipping region, etc (and, as you can see, you prbly will need to).

You may also need to adjust `delay` on your system depending on how efficient the rendering is (i.e. make it a larger number if it comes back blank).